# Why does OpenSSL automatically send me Terminal mail?

Tags: terminal, cron, email, openssl

I for some reason am getting messages from OpenSSL constantly (not literally constantly, but every hour or so) sent to my Terminal mail box saying:

Message 1

```
Subject: Cron <bymanj@dhcp-10-32-180-238> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.3/bin/openssl-osx-ca /usr/local/bin/brew
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=bymanj>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=bymanj>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/bymanj>
Date: Wed,  4 Sep 2013 18:00:01 -0400 (EDT)

/bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.3/bin/openssl-osx-ca: No such file or directory
```

And I cannot seem to get rid of the messages, even when I delete them. Is there something wrong with my OpenSSl install?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using OS X with Homebrew. If so: looks like it to me. you should probably reinstall, IMHO. can't hurt.

Comment: You have a cronjob to run a command that doesn't exist. Disable it.

Answer (score 5):

You have apparently used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install the `openssh-osx-ca` script, probably from the [raggi/ale keg](https://github.com/raggi/homebrew-ale).

I just installed it, and it does add a `crontab` entry matching your problem report. Here, the file you're getting email complaints about does exist.

The most likely reason you're getting this is that you later uninstalled this package, since that leaves behind the `crontab` entry. So, say `crontab -e` and remove the line containing `openssl-osx-ca`.

If you didn't intentionally remove it, and you want this package, reinstall it:

```
$ brew reinstall openssl-osx-ca
```

You might also want to give `brew doctor` a try. Files belonging to Homebrew packages shouldn't just disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a message like the following in your inbox:

```
From lex@computername.localdomain  Sat Feb 11 09:00:01 2017
Return-Path: <lex@computername.localdomain>
X-Original-To: lex
Delivered-To: lex@computername.localdomain
Received: by computername.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 501)
    id 0328B1389A2B; Sat, 11 Feb 2017 09:00:00 -0500 (EST)
From: lex@computername.localdomain (Cron Daemon)
To: lex@computername.localdomain
Subject: Cron <lex@computername> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.5/bin/openssl-osx-ca /usr/local/bin/brew
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=lex>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=lex>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/lex>
Message-Id: <20170211140001.0328B1389A2B@computername.localdomain>
Date: Sat, 11 Feb 2017 09:00:00 -0500 (EST)

/bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.5/bin/openssl-osx-ca: No such file or directory
```

Notice the Subject line.

Check your crontab

```
$ crontab -l
@hourly /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca/1.0.5/bin/openssl-osx-ca /usr/local/bin/brew
```

Remove the openssl-osx-ca line:

```
(crontab -l | grep -v openssl-osx-ca) | crontab -
```

Check if you have an older version of installed via homebrew.

Run this command to see what versions you have:

```
find /usr/local/Cellar/openssl-osx-ca -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

To remove all but latest version of openssl-osx-ca run the following command:

```
brew cleanup openssl-osx-ca
```

Lastly, you probably want to remove your mail messages.  If so, run the following command:

```
cp /dev/null /var/mail/$USER
```